# Get network speed Windows 2003 cmd (Batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, cmd, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to get the network speed (network adapter speed) in Windows Server 2003.
I tried to get the speed with the command :

```
wmic nic where "MacAddress is not null" get Name, Speed
```

But the result only contains the name of the adapters, the speed column is empty.

Is there any other way to find it?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the NICs connected? The reported `Speed` is the speed of the respective connections, not the max supported speed of the adapter itself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is using a vbs Script.

```
Dim strQuery, strQuery2, objLocator, objWMI, objItem, objItem2, colItems, colItems2, resultString, nicName
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface"
strQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter"
Set objLocator = CreateObject( "WbemScripting.SWbemLocator" )
Set objWMI = objLocator.ConnectServer( ".", "root\CIMV2" )
objWMI.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3
Set colItems2 = objWMI.ExecQuery( strQuery2, "WQL", 0 )
Set colItems = objWMI.ExecQuery( strQuery, "WQL", 0 )
resultString = ""
For Each objItem2 In colItems2
 If objItem2.NetConnectionStatus = 2 Then
  nicName = Mid(objItem2.Name, 1, 5)
  resultString = resultString & objItem2.Name

  For Each objItem In colItems
   If Mid(objItem.Name, 1, 5) = nicName Then
    resultString = resultString & " " & objItem.CurrentBandwidth & VbCrLf
   End If
  Next
 End If
Next
Set objLocator = Nothing
Set objWMI = Nothing
Set colItems = Nothing
Set colItems2 = Nothing

WScript.Echo resultString
```

Thank you!